# Min of non-repeating elements in a list, in linear time

Tags: algorithm, list, traversal

Given an unsorted list of numbers (can be int or double), give algorithm to find min of non-repeating elements, in one traversal of list and linear time. (No restriction on space)

E.g.

```
Given list is [2, 7, 9, 5, 2, 8, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1]   
Non-repeating elements are [7, 9, 8, 3, 6]  
Min non-repeating element is 3
```

I tried this by making two hash-sets, one to store non-repeating elements and the other to store repeating elements, and a variable to store min of non-repeating hash-set. This can give me linear time in few cases, but not in all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should give you linear complexity for all cases. Can you show your code?

Comment: What is the particular case that gives unexpected result? Is there any constraints for element in the list?

Comment: By _not linear_, do you mean more than one traversal of the linked list?

Comment: You cannot know if an item is repeated of not, before you reach the end of the list. Hence you cannot in parallel have one variable to hold the minimum of non repeated items, because at any point, it might turn out, that you minimum is a repeated item after all.

Comment: ^ Exactly. Even if you try maintaining a second variable to hold the second_minimum, even that could be repeated. There's got to be some clever way of doing this

Answer (score 2):

First, find all non-repeating items, e.g. hashmap with key=item and value=occurences.

Next, go through hashmap and find min key where value is 1.

This is linear in O(2n)

Comment: The question clearly states that it has to be done in a single traversal -_-

Comment: I'm traversing the list only once. Traversing the hashmap is something different.

Comment: It's an easy trap to fall into though - I'd considered a non-tail-recursive approach to the problem that added to a hashmap before the recursive call and compared values after the recursive call until I realized it was essentially using the recursion stack as a second traversal. A number of ways of approaching this problem seem to turn out to involve additional traversal of list elements on some level, even if it is less overt, in order to stay linear time.

Comment: @SevenStarConstellation the OP said that the algorithm proposed in the question was "not always linear". Ridcully's *is* linear, and only does a single pass on the original array. I feel that this answer is correct (or as correct as anyone can make it): any data-structure is going to make internal passes over the data it collects, because that is what data structures are *for*: holding data for efficient later use.

Comment: @tucuxi Fair enough. If this was a problem that was posed to G_S at some point I have to admit I'm curious what its "official", if any, solution was.

Answer (score -1):

Use Fibonacci Heaps (FH) - with Min

- Make Heap \theta(1) in amortized.
- Insert \theta(1) in amortized.
- Find_Minimum \theta(1) in amortized.
- Extract_The_Mininimum O(log n) in amortized.
- Increase_Key \theta(1) in amortized.

---

```
for i in L
   If i == Find_Min(FH)                // O(1) since the min in the top of the list.
     Increase_key(min(FH), the_max_number)// \theta(1) in amortized.
   else
     Insert(FG)                       // \theta(1) in amortized.
if Find_Min(FH) == the_max_number
   return nil
else
   return Find_Min(FH)
```

Instead of `Extract_The_Mininimum` use increase key set to the_max_number.

You will have Theta(n) in amortizes cost. See Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest at chapter 18.

Comment: Could you please clarify? If checking the current min is O(1) shouldn't `extract-min` and `decrease-key` be the FH operations instead of `extract-max` and `increase-key` (but then in that case what is being referred to by "set to `the_max_number`")?

Comment: In a min FH isn't it the case that increasing the current minimum key requires looking for a new minimum (essentially equivalent to `extract-min` followed by `insert` with the new value)? I may be missing something but it looks as though `Increase_key(min(FH), the_max_number)` would still amortize to O(log n) instead of \theta(1), since if compared to `decrease_key` on the immediate child of the increased node the guarantee that the only possible new minimum is the child's value is gone, requiring a search over roots as for `extract-min`.

Comment: `increase_key` is not implemented by `extract-min` followed by `insert` See CLC

Comment: Could you please spell out CLC and add a link to, say, its amazon page, assuming it is not available legally online? I am not familiar with the acronym.